# iOS saving UIImage in plist via file or via nsdata?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, save, nsdata

I am trying to save a Dictionary in a plist.
One of the dictionary keys is an image.

I have two options (both tried and work), though not exactly sure which is better?

1) Saving the image in Documents folder as file + saving filename in plist for later retrieval?

2) Saving the NSData of the image directly in the plist for later retrieval?

I have tried both methods, and both work just fine. I am able to save and retrieve the images.

My question is: are there any pros / cons for one way over the other?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

more clarification: the images are from the camera, and I save them using

```
NSData *imageData  = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7f);
[imageData writeToFile:[SAD.myE documentsPathForFileName:@"testImage.jpg"] atomically:YES]; //Write the file
```

and I then scale them down, and save a smaller image to be used in a tableView, one image per cell.

As I understand, it is better to save them as files in Documents directory and retrieve them that way in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the way you save and more importantly, the way you consume the data later on.

Saving in most cases can be offloaded to the background, then it is not your bottleneck and you are free to do whatever you want

Reading the data often be a subject of a time constrains e.g. you are displaying pictures in a table view, this means you want to separate one image per file so you can read as atomic as possible. Or you might need random access - then you are better off by serializing all the data except for binary blobs into SQLite

All and all if you can give an sample of data consumption.

To clarify, if you are optimizing for reading - the best option is to save decompressed image so it won't even have to parse png or jpg format

Comment: Thanks for answer. See edit above. I get a UIImage from the imagePickerController, so save it to a file, save the name in the plist and retrieve it that way in the tableView via background thread?

Comment: That sounds like the most suitable generic solution. Again, if disk space is not a concern, and you are planning only to display the image afterwards, consider decompressing image prior to saving it to the disk

Comment: how do I decompress the image? I have a UIImage to play with.

Comment: I'm not next to my laptop right now, so the best example I can find is this https://gist.github.com/PaulSolt/739132 :) also make sure to check the performance on targeted iOS - it varies from version to version

Comment: Cool, i will look at it and try it out and get back to you! :) Thanks!

Comment: Ended up using the https://gist.github.com/jamztang/1257111, it reduced the filesize dramatically and seems to be doing the job... take a look :)

Comment: I think it just decompressed the image at runtime (AFNetworking using the same trick to decompress received images so you can display them faster). So it's important to note that you have to do it prior to displaying every time after texting it from the disk (as oppose to doing it once before you save it to the disk). The only thing that seems to be missing is adjustment for the display scale - you might end up getting images twice as big. But yes, it's a good solution:)

Comment: Cool.. Accepted as answered since it was perfectly elaborate. Thanks once more.

Comment: Hope it helped as well. Cheers:)

Answer (score 1):

Would definitely recommend saving the `UIImage` to a file and keeping the filename in your plist. Plists aren't really meant to do such heavy lifting to store large amounts of data. You will see better performance by saving to a file.

Comment: agreed with @Stonz2. Just gave it a whirl myself and def much much better performance.